# ¿Cómo utilizar un "modal dispose" en un botón?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Tengo una página que muestra una tabla, y hay una opción para ver los datos, sólo que cuando se abre un segundo modal, se abre con los datos del primer.

Yo estaba viendo unos ejemplos de modales y encontré ese "dispose" sólo que quería saber cómo utilizar, o si hay una manera mejor de cerrar el modal y abrirlo como si fuera la primera vez abierta.

Comment: No se entiende para nada la pregunta.. intenta redactarla de otra manera, date una vuelta por [acá](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) así podes editar la pregunta y armarla de modo correcto, así es posible entenderte y ayudarte

Comment: ¿te referís a abrir dos modales al mismo tiempo, o cuando cerras uno abrís el segundo?

Comment: Cuando se cierra el primero para abrir el segundo.

Comment: Esto puede ocurrir por diferentes motivos, debes incluir el código en la pregunta para que podamos ver y reproducir el problema, y de esa manera ayudarte con tu caso particular. Lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] para más información y edita la pregunta con las recomendaciones que encontrarás allí.

Comment: Y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento general (y así ganar una nueva medalla).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

primero que nada, es totalmente recomendable leer la [documentación de bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/), ya que es muy completa.

Con la poca información que hay en tu pregunta, voy a intentar orientarte lo mejor posible.

> Para ocultar los modales de bootstrap 4 existen dos métodos
>
> **hide**
>
> ```
> $('#myModal').modal('hide')
> ```
>
> que provoca que el modal se oculte
>
> **dispose**
>
> ```
> $('#myModal').modal('dispose')
> ```
>
> en este segundo caso, el modal se **destruirá** por lo que no podrías
>   volver a mostrarlo bajo ninguna circunstancia.

Ya teniendo en cuenta esto, para tu caso, posiblemente sea muy
 importante conocer los eventos asociados, ya que con estos, podrías
 limpiar y reescribir el contenido que se muestra en tu modal
 dinámicamente

> **show.bs.modal**
>
> Este evento se dispara de modo instantáneo cuando llamamos al método
>   `.show()`
>
> **shown.bs.modal**
>
> En este caso es algo similar, solo que se disparará al momento de que
>   el `css` haya cambiado, y el modal ya sea visible por el usuario
>
> **hide.bs.modal**
>
> Al igual que el primero con `.show()`, este evento se dispara
>   instantáneamente al ejecutar el método `.hide()`
>
> **hidden.bs.modal**
>
> Tiene un funcionamiento igual al anterior, pero espera a que la
>   transición `css` haya finalizado, osea, que el modal ya no sea visible
>   para el usuario

Ahora, poniendo esto en contexto, en tu caso, podrías utilizar el evento `show.bs.modal` para alterar la información del modal antes de mostrarla por pantalla, un pequeño ejemplo, podría ser algo así

```js
var count = 0;
$('#exampleModalCenter').on('show.bs.modal', function(){
count++;  
        //Uso el método .empty() para eliminar todo el contenido dentro de .modal-body
  $('#exampleModalCenter .modal-body').empty();
    $('#exampleModalCenter .modal-body').append("El contenido es dinámico, esta es la vez número "+count+" que abriste el modal!");

})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
  Abrir modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Donde cada vez que abras el modal, el evento `show.bs.modal` se encarga de incrementar el contador y modificar el cuerpo del modal de modo dinámico

Espero que sea lo que andabas buscando y lo entiendas de la mejor manera, saludos y éxitos!

Comment: se agradece tu ayuda, pero tienes la suficiente reputación para saber que preguntas tan poco claras y tan amplias que no muestran una ruta clara en el código no se deben responder

Comment: @AlfredoPaz la respondí porque me dio la impresión de que, si bien esta incompleta, es una pregunta que no esta respondida (o al menos no la encontre) en stackoverflow en español, entonces, para la persona que busque en un futuro, va a encontrar esta respuesta